# Is there a open source .NET CMS that has support for Arabic language?

Tags: .net, open-source, content-management-system

Is there a open source .NET CMS that has support for Arabic language? Anyone here has an experience with using one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe umbraco supports Arabic.

http://umbraco.org/

I recently did some research into how much work it would be to convert one of our existing multi lingual sites to include Arabic.

The biggest issue was making the back end WYSIWYG editor (TinyMCE) RTL. However this turned out to be quite simple - just a case of enabling the RTL buttons in the config. Found here http://forum.umbraco.org/yaf_postst9084_How-can-we-use-incomplete-xml-langauge-file-in-umbraco.aspx

I'm not sure whether umbraco's back end actually can be displayed in Arabic.

Answer (score 3):

[Composite C1](http://composite.net) has excellent Foreign language support and support RTL languages. It's a Danish outfit that took a stable commercial product and open sourced it. It's got a [FANTASTIC UI](http://users.composite.net/User-Guide/User-Guide/Multiple-languages) for multiple languages as well. Click on the page (in a tree structure) and just click Translate.

We are using it for French and English and it's a breeze for the translators.

In addition, the back-end has been localized into a couple of several languages already.

Answer (score 0):

Most .NET based stuff are using Unicode so they (in theory) should support any languages. Most of them are easily translatable, too.

So, you're good to go with any of them.
Perhaps you should look at DotNetNuke or Umbraco or Sense/Net, those are big ones.